# keyboard shortcut for Android Studio:ctrl+o

Tags: android, fragment, shortcut

keyboard shortcut for Android Studio of "ctrl+o ": override base class methods in the current class .At the same time ,I konw the function "onCreateView"  is a member function of class 'Fragment'.But when I  see the member functions of class 'Fragment' by 'ctrl+o' programing with Android Studio,I do not find the function "onCreateView".I do not know why not.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM93g.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIgRD.png)

Comment: format your question as in it's current state, iam not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Because it is probably **already** overridden. Check your class and you will see that there already exists the

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Rather than trying to override it 'again', which is not possible, redefine the one already there however you like.

Comment: Excuse me.What I say is the function "onCreateView"  not "onCreate"